# Upload video file from Unity to Python over Http

Tags: python, file, http, unity-game-engine, file-upload

I am trying to upload a video file from an Unity client to a python server, but when I have tried to do it with `UnityWebRequest` in Unity and `http` module in python, but the server receives invalid video file.

My question is how to upload a video file from Unity to python over Http?

**This is my code in Unity:**

```
IEnumerator StartUploadCoroutine()
{
    // Show a load file dialog and wait for a response from user
    yield return FileBrowser.WaitForLoadDialog(false, null, "Load File", "Load");

    isOpen = false;
    // Upload File to movie server
    if (FileBrowser.Success)
    {
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(FileBrowser.Result);
        StartCoroutine(UploadCoroutine(reader)); // upload file to server;
    }
}

/* Upload the chosen video file to the movie server */
IEnumerator UploadCoroutine(StreamReader reader)
{
    UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Post(videoPlayerManager.GetServerIp() + ":" + port.ToString(), reader.ReadToEnd());
    yield return www.SendWebRequest();

    if (www.isNetworkError || www.isHttpError)
    {
        Debug.Log(www.error);
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("Form upload complete!");
    }
}
```

**And this is my Python code:**

```
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer

class HandleRequests(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):

    def do_POST(self):
        '''Reads post request body'''
        content_length = int(self.headers['Content-Length'])
        body = self.rfile.read(content_length)
        self.send_response(200)
        self.end_headers()
        outF = open("myOutFile.mp4", "wb")
        outF.write(body)


host = "127.0.0.1"
port = 9999

HTTPServer((host, port), HandleRequests).serve_forever()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out thanks to > MohammadReza Arashiyan

My problem was sending the file from Unity as string instead of a bytes array.
I have changed my python code to Flask server so I could easily get the file from the post request, and I ended up with these codes:

**This is my code in Unity:**

```
IEnumerator StartUploadCoroutine()
{
    // Show a load file dialog and wait for a response from user
    yield return FileBrowser.WaitForLoadDialog(false, null, "Load File", "Load");

    isOpen = false;
    // Upload File to movie server
    if (FileBrowser.Success)
    {
        StartCoroutine(UploadCoroutine(FileBrowser.Result)); // upload file to server;
    }
}

/* Upload the chosen video file to the movie server */
IEnumerator UploadCoroutine(string filePath)
{
    WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
    form.AddBinaryData("vidFile", File.ReadAllBytes(filePath));
    UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Post(videoPlayerManager.GetServerUrl(), form);
    yield return www.SendWebRequest();

    if (www.isNetworkError || www.isHttpError)
    {
        Debug.Log(www.error);
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("Form upload complete!");
    }
}
```

**And this is my Python code:**

```
import os
from flask import Flask, request, send_from_directory
from gevent.pywsgi import WSGIServer

IP = "127.0.0.1"
PORT = 9999

# set the project root directory as the static folder
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def DownloadFile():
    # request.form to get form parameter
    vidFile = request.files["vidFile"].read()
    outF = open("myOutFile.mp4", "wb")
    outF.write(vidFile)

    return ''

if __name__ == "__main__":
    http_server = WSGIServer((IP, PORT), app)
    http_server.serve_forever()
```

Answer (score 3):

I think in uploading a file (any extension) to a server, Encodings are not important.

Look for two things:

1. Check that your local video file and uploaded video file have the same Size. if they don't match, it means that you have a problem with uploading progress. ([Check here](https://forum.unity.com/threads/2-simple-scripts-to-upload-files-to-a-http-server-and-free-hosting-recommendation.144261/))
2. You are using POST method to upload the video. It means that the whole of the file will upload to your server and then your python script can use it on 'body' variable. I files size match, I can suggest you use a framework like [Flask](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/) as server-side python script.